# There are mistakes during npm install

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am new in React and WebPack. I actually don't have any experience with such problems.
I tried to set up webpack, everything was ok. But after installing some packages during development, I started to get such mistakes. I tried to use --legacy-peer-deps, but it does not help me solve these problems.
If you know what packages to change or maybe update and how to fix it, thank you in advance!

```
While resolving: extract-text-webpack-plugin@3.0.2
npm ERR! Found: webpack@5.74.0
npm ERR! node_modules/webpack
npm ERR!   dev webpack@"^5.74.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer webpack@">=4.43.0 <6.0.0" from @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin@0.5.8
npm ERR!   node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin
npm ERR!     @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin@"^0.5.3" from @storybook/react@6.5.12
npm ERR!     node_modules/@storybook/react
npm ERR!       dev @storybook/react@"^6.5.12" from the root project
npm ERR!   25 more (@storybook/builder-webpack5, @storybook/core, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer webpack@"^3.1.0" from extract-text-webpack-plugin@3.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin
npm ERR!   dev extract-text-webpack-plugin@"^3.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: webpack@3.12.0
npm ERR! node_modules/webpack
npm ERR!   peer webpack@"^3.1.0" from extract-text-webpack-plugin@3.0.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin
npm ERR!     dev extract-text-webpack-plugin@"^3.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /home/user/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
```

my package.json is below

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.19.1",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.18.6",
    "@marshallofsound/webpack-asset-relocator-loader": "^0.5.0",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.5.12",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.5.12",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^6.5.12",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.5.12",
    "@storybook/builder-webpack5": "^6.5.12",
    "@storybook/manager-webpack5": "^6.5.12",
    "@storybook/preset-scss": "^1.0.3",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.5.12",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.13",
    "@testing-library/dom": "^8.18.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "12",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "@types/jest": "^29.0.2",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "@types/react-transition-group": "^4.4.5",
    "@types/webpack-env": "^1.16.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.37.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.37.0",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "css-loader": "^5.2.4",
    "cz-conventional-changelog": "3.3.0",
    "eslint": "^7.22.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-alias": "^1.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.31.8",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "^6.2.4",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.1",
    "jest": "^29.0.3",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.0.3",
    "less": "^4.1.1",
    "less-loader": "8.1.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.5.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.13.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^18.2.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "2.3.1",
    "sass": "^1.54.9",
    "sass-loader": "^13.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "ts-jest": "^29.0.1",
    "ts-loader": "^9.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.8.3",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@hot-loader/react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "@types/node-sass": "^4.11.3",
    "adjust-sourcemap-loader": "1.2.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "classnames": "^2.3.2",
    "css-modules-typescript-loader": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-padding": "^0.0.4",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "node-sass": "^7.0.3",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.4.5",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript-css-modules": "^1.0.4"
  },
```

Comment: Try it please:```npm install --force```. Hope it would work.

Comment: It helps, but the problem does not leave. There is a conflict among packages. And I am trying to find out how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`

Comment: Yes, it helps. But if I want to install packages again, I get the same error. That is why I want to understand how to fix it forever

Answer (score 0):

Seems your node version and project requirements conflict. First, uninstall node from your machine:
[from this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x)
And install the latest version of node from here:
[node installation](https://nodejs.org/en/)

Hope it would work.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to downgrade the node version using nvm

Comment: The problem is not in Node version. My colleague cannot also instal packages and get the same error. Problem is in versions of packages which I cannot fix.

Comment: I've got the same issue and it was fixed with node versions change
is there any chance that i can take a look at this project I'm curious